# Execute query on multiple sqlite databases in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have more than 400 sqlite databases. I need to query on these databases. Like simple `SELECT.....` query to get results.

I don't know weather it is possible within single query.

Current logic is.

```
foreach(FileInfo finf in Files)
{
    // query one database get result 
    Datatable results = execute();
    // merge Datatable with new one.
}
```

at the end we get all database results in single datatable.

Is anyone having better solution for querying multiple databases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes i tried but maximum results are related to attach database. Which is inconvenience to me. It is same as current logic

Comment: your solution is not bad, but close unused SqLiteConnection(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a single result set with SQLite you have to join all the databases by the [ATTACH command](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_attach_database.htm) giving to each one a different alias, then build a sql statement which group the data into a single result set by the [SELECT ... UNION command](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm).

For example:

```
 - ATTACH DATABASE 'Database1' As 'DB1';
 - ATTACH DATABASE 'Database2' As 'DB2';
```

Then :

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.MyTable

UNION

SELECT * FROM DB2.MyTable
```

Comment: I have more than 400 database. max limit of sqlite attach database is 62. http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Query by group og 62 queries and merge the results into DataTable object.